# OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I am making a pyttsx3 chat bot however this error occurred:

```
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This error also occurred:

```
KeyError: None
```

Here is my code:

```
import pyttsx3

def say(sp):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(sp)
    engine.runandwait()
    
say("Hello my name is Neuron")
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: apt install espeak

Answer (score 21):

To install **espeak** on ubuntu or any of the debian based OS, enter the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo apt install espeak
```

To use pyttsx3 python library, install the following using terminal:

`pip3 install pyttsx3`
`sudo apt install espeak`
`pip3 install pyaudio` or use
`sudo apt install python3-pyaudio`

Answer (score 9):

**pyttsx3** uses the **espeak** library for speech synthesis.

The error says that python cannot find this library.

I work on Arch (Linux) and I solved this problem by:

```
sudo pacman -S espeak
```

For Ubuntu you can do it by:

```
sudo apt install espeak
```

For Windows unfortunately I don't know the answer. Maybe you can install the library from the internet.

Answer (score 9):

I face the same problem on my ubuntu 20.04
at first install espeak or libespeak-dev

```
$ sudo apt install espeak
```

or

```
$ sudo apt install libespeak-dev
```

and after installing pyttsx3 on my venv

```
$ pip install pyttsx3
```

and it works fine with me hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt install libespeak-dev
```

This package provides eSpeak development files needed for compilation with the espeak shared library. Your code will works fine after install it. I had the same issu and I resolved it with this command.

Comment: Please provide more information on what this command does, and why it works.

Answer (score 2):

For arch the problem can be solved by installing espeak-ng-extended-git

```
yay -S espeak-ng-extended-git
```

Answer (score 0):

To install eSpeak on manjaro i had to install it like:

```
pamac install espeak-ng
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
pip install PyAudio
```

this will definitely help you to run you code successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add some information regarding answers above for arch\manjaro linux:

```
sudo pamac install espeak-ng
```

This would help to install correct library.
But for python use you might use **pyttsx3** which is using **libespeak**. And mistake happens because for espeak-ng there is no such library.

And to resolve it you need to create a **symbol link** to a library within espeak-ng install
like

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libespeak-ng.so.1 /usr/lib/libespeak.so.1
```

It will allow to "switch" calls from **libespeak** to **libespeak-ng** library.