# OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory n ot solved after installing espeak and libespeak1

Tags: python-3.x, linux, google-colaboratory

after seeing the solution of above problem here
[OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274843/oserror-libespeak-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)
when i installed espeak in linux
after that also same problem occured
also i reboot the system after installing if this works it also didn't work
I was doing this code on google collab
i also installed libespeak1
again same problem occured

Answer (score 0):

Install espeak

for ubuntu:
`sudo apt install espeak`

Comment: Are there any installation instructions for other distributions?