Is there a way to use pyttsx3 or any other TTS in pydroid
I want to make a program using TTS in pydroid but I am getting libespeak.so.1 not found error.
I have tried pyttsx3 and gtts but nothing is working, I am making a program that uses openai and pyttsx3 to make a voice assistant,so is there a way to use pyttsx3 in pydroid Android ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

hi, for ubuntu/debian please check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274843/oserror-libespeak-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo
